# rust read_line() does not seam to be working properly

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am new to Rust. I am following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygL_xcavzQ4&t=451s). Here I am trying to get an input from user using `stdin::read_line()`. But for some reason `read_line()` seams to be executing start the very start of the run process. And doing so the application is not printing my message/prompt for the user, which is suppoesed to print right before the `read_line()`.

I've tried looking on google but did not found anything on this issue. I am not sure what is the reason for this kind of behaviour. I've also tried changing my terminals although I don't think this have anything to do with this issue, but just in case.

This is happening in both the cases 1). `cargo run` and `cargo build` -> `<running my app from terninal>`.

It would be very helpful is someone can point out what it is that I am doing wrong.

My code:

```
use std::io;

fn main()
{
    print!("What is your Name?->");
    let mut user_name: String = String::new();
    let greeting = "Nice to meet you.";
    
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut user_name).expect("<Did note receive anything from user.>");
    print!("Hello {}!, {}", user_name.trim_end(), greeting);
}
```

OutPut for `cargo build`:

```
first_project\target\debug [ master][?]
❯ ls
build/  deps/  examples/  first_project.d  first_project.exe*  first_project.pdb  incremental/

first_project\target\debug [ master][?]
❯ ./first_project
[This is my input]  
What is your Name?->Hello [This is my input]!, Nice to meet you.
first_project\target\debug [ master][?][⏱ 12s]
❯
```

Out Put for `cargo run`:

```
first_project\target\debug [ master][?]
❯ cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.03s
     Running `.\first_project.exe`
[this is my input]  
What is your Name?->Hello [this is my input]!, Nice to meet you.
first_project\target\debug [ master][?][⏱ 6s]
❯
```